# c++ iterator vs pointer for vector access

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

For a vector I can use both an iterator and a pointer to access its elements and iterate through them, for example:

```
std::vector<int> x {0, 1, 2};
std::vector<int>::iterator it = x.begin();
int *begin = &x[0];
```

Both the iterator and the pointer would give access to the same object. However, as far as I know, the preferred way is to use iterators (for any containers other than arrays). Is there a particular reason for this? (Other than the fact that in my creation of begin I assume the container has a [ ] operation defined.)

Comment: Try a pointer with a `std::list`.

Comment: That's because std::list doesn't provide an subscript operator. Is this the only reason then? But then std::list needs to provide a .begin() operation, which is not much more difficult than a writing a [ ] operation, so why is that preferred?

Comment: Oops, I read that part of the post, too. Pretend I said `std::deque`. Anyway, pointers are dumb. Iterators have expected semantics for all containers, no matter what they have to do to iterate through it. It doesn't even have to be a container.

Comment: Because your container of choice is not guaranteed to have contiguous memory for element storage unless the standard defines it as such. The standard for `std::vector<>` makes that warrant; containers like `std::list<>` do not. If you want to write code that will (as efficiently as possible) be transparent, use iterators. they're what's for dinner. (and you could have used `x.data()` in your sample code if you have C++11, btw).

Comment: All right that clears it up, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Use iterators unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise. Several important operations (e.g. `insert`, `erase`, etc.) require iterators, so you'll often need to cough one up anyway. Iterators also work really nicely with algorithms to accomplish things that are complex of awkward to do with explicit loops. Plus, they're generic enough to work for all containers, not just `vector` and `string`.

Of course if you're in a situation which does require a pointer (e.g. interacting with a C API, or interacting across a module boundary) you shouldn't feel "dirty" about doing that either -- pointers are fine. Just use them where necessary.

Finally, in the specific case of vector and string, be sure to consider indices. Some algorithms are more readable using them and they have the advantage that they are never invalidated if the vector is forced to reallocate or something like that. (Just note that this locks you into vector or string and can make changing containers later difficult)